# How to disable predictive text in android programatically on html page of the hybrid application

Tags: android, samsung-galaxy

We have a issue with predictive text in hybrid applications of Android. Whenever user enters space in the text field, It auto populates to a random value and do not allow the user to enter a valid value. This behaves usual when we disable predictive text from settings of the mobile.But, asking the user to disable the predictive text is not a good practice. The core problem is that the attributes of the text field, auto_correct and auto_complete are not working for below list of samsung devices to disable the predictive text at field level.
Can someone suggest a work around to handle this programatically without asking the user manually to disable the predictive text.

Galaxy S5 LTE-A (kccat6)
OS Android 5.0

Device Galaxy S6 (zeroflte)
OS Android 6.0

Device Galaxy S4 (jflte)
OS Android 5.0

Device Galaxy S6 Edge (zerolte)
OS Android 6.0

Device Galaxy S6 (zeroflte)
OS Android 6.0

Device Galaxy S5 (klte)
OS Android 5.0

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<input type="text" id="myText" name="myText" autocomplete='off'/>
```

Or

```
formElement.setAttribute( "autocomplete", "off" );
```

Comment: Thanks Bala, I have already tried this. As mentioned in the description these attributes are not working for the list the devices mentioned. I am looking for alternative workaround to handle this programatically.